# How to make own set of brushes when new file open?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, brush

Every time when I open new .ai file I remove all default brushes cuz they no need me. How to make that each time when I open Illustrator I'll have my own set of brushes?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load in your brushes how you'd like them and then save your Illustrator doc as a template file (`.ait`) and then copy it into the folder where your new doc profiles are stored;

```
%APPDATA%\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator {version} Settings\en_US\x64\New Document Profiles
```

Now, restart Illustrator, when opening a new doc, just choose that template under **Profile**.